# Why do I get one more number of bytes reported in a file?

Tags: linux, files

Why do I get one byte more reported? I do not have a newline at the end. I tested other files with similar result. Using linux 3.2.

```
$ cat testfile.txt 
aabbcd

$ wc -c testfile.txt 
7 testfile.txt
```

Similarly I get one more number of bytes reported if I use c++:

```
...
file(filename, std::ifstream::in | std::ios::binary);
file.seekg(0, std::ifstream::end);
int fsize = file.tellg();
...
```

The text aabbcd consist of 6 characters, in ASCII encoding that should be 6 bytes.
Why do I get 7 bytes reported?

Note: I happend to have characters in the example, but I care only about the bytes, not text, not formatted input.

Comment: Could you do `od -x testfile.txt` on the file and add the result to your question?

Comment: Maybe there's a stray line feed at the end of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`vi` and many other editors *add an extra line feed to the end of the file even if you don't add one manually*. For example, writing `aabbcd` in vi, not pressing return and saving gives a file that `od -x` dumps as;

```
0000000      6161    6262    6463    000a
0000007
```

...which is (a little endian dump of) `aabbcd` + line feed.

`ls -l` will also show the file as 7 bytes;

```
$ ls -l testfile.txt 
-rw-r--r--  1 me  staff  7 Jul 26 09:52 testfile.txt
```

Most likely, this is the case with your file too.

Comment: I even get that with: $ echo -e '\n' > linefeed2; $ od -A n -x linefeed2; which prints: 0a0a

Comment: Why do editors add an extra line feed ?  Is it necessary ?